# Understanding Cartan-Hadamard theorem

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth compact Riemannian manifold of dimension at least 3. Does the Hopf-Rinow theorem imply that $(M,g)$ is a complete Riemannian manifold? I.e. is a compact Riemannian manifold always complete?

If so, then can we conclude from the Cartan-Hadamard theorem that if $(M,g)$ is a compact and simply connected Riemannian manifold, then it must have positive sectional curvature?

If so, this seems to contradict the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074190/ricci-curvature-version-of-cartan-hadamard-theorem) question, which says that any Riemannian manifold of dimension at least 3 admits a complete Ricci negative metric.

Where is the error in my reasoning?

What is an example of a sphere with negative sectional or Ricci curvature?

Comment: Any compact metric space is complete. Nothing special about Riemannian manifold. Second paragraph is wrong. And for the last paragraph, Cartan Hadamard will give you a contradiction, i.e, if that is true then exponential map gives you a diffeomorphism with Euclidean space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Hopf-Rinow Theorem states that if $(M, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold such that the closed and bounded subsets are compact, then $(M, g)$ is complete. If $M$ is compact, then every closed subset is compact, so $(M, g)$ is complete.

The Cartan-Hadamard Theorem states that if $(M, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold with non-positive sectional curvature, then its universal cover is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $M$ is compact and simply connected, then it is its own universal cover which is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $M$ cannot admit a Riemannian metric with non-positive sectional curvature. However, that does not imply that $M$ must admit a metric of positive sectional curvature.  For example, the $K3$ surface is a compact, simply connected four-manifold which cannot admit a metric with positive sectional curvature (it can't even admit a metric with positive *scalar* curvature). All we can deduce from the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem is that for any metric on a compact, simply connected manifold $M$, there is a point $p \in M$ and a two-plane $\Pi \in \operatorname{Gr}_2(T_pM)$ such that $K(\Pi) > 0$.

A sphere can't have negative sectional curvature, otherwise it would have universal cover $\mathbb{R}^n$ by Cartan-Hadamard.